# PHP Mail reply-to not being set

Tags: php

I'm using the following which sends email fine but doesn't set the reply-to address and I can't figure out why.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email_addr'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$body = $_POST['body'];

$body = stripslashes($body);

$message = "Email from site.\n\n
From: $name\n
Email: $email\n
Phone: $phone\n\n
Message: $body";

$to      = 'darren@mysite.com';
$subject = 'From Site';
$message = $message;
$headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Use PHPmailer for sending mails..

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but the headers could be case sensitive. From memory, it's meant to be `Reply-to` (lowercase *"t"*)

Comment: Have checked weather your $email field is not blank?

Comment: $email field def not blank, headers are correct - weird